# group one column according to another column and sum of third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a", "a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a"],
       'gender': ["male", "female", "female", "female", "male","male","male","female","female", 
                  "female", "male","male","male", "male"],
      'year':[2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2019],
      'month':[1, 12, 4, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 1, 12, 4, 3, 6 ],
      'count':[100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90]})
```

It shows the name, gender, birth year and the birth month, and the number of people.

For example, in 2005 January there were 100 babies named “a”. I want to find top-10 frequent names for males and females, just as below:

[image]

```
df.sort_values(['gender','count'],ascending=False,inplace=True)
male = df[df['gender']=='male']['name'].head(10).to_list()
female = df[df['gender']=='female']['name'].head(10).to_list()
results = pd.DataFrame({'Male':pd.Series(male),'Female':pd.Series(female)})
print (results)
```

but apparently it gives duplicated amounts for example 5 a instead of total amount for a.I need to sum them up for example we have 100 'a' in 2005 and 100 'a' in 2009 and so on. so in total we need to add them up like 100+ 100 and.the final result must be like a is male and totally in 10 years 500 people were named a and so on.

Comment: Are you grouping by the year or the month of the year?

Comment: I need the total amount. Ex in year 2005 all months how many 'a's are there? and in all years how many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a multiple groupby:

```
by_year = df.groupby(['year', 'gender', 'name']).agg({'count': 'sum'})
print(by_year)

total = by_year.groupby(['gender', 'name']).agg({'count': 'sum'})
print(total)
```

If not, please further specify an expected result.

Answer (score 2):

First aggregate `sum` for `count` column, then select `male` and `female` with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and return index values for names:

```
s = df.groupby(['gender','name'])['count'].sum()

results = pd.DataFrame({'Male':pd.Series(s.loc['male'].nlargest(10).index),
                        'Female':pd.Series(s.loc['female'].nlargest(10).index)})
print (results)

  Male Female
0    a      b
1    d      d
2    e      c
3  NaN      a
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i asked

Comment: @nemo92world So why is accepted another answer? Was it accident?